# Are ARG values passed to scripts executed with RUN

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If I have ARG values and then RUN a script in my Dockerfile, will that script be able to access those values while it runs during build time?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I checked it and it seems to work in my limited example:

```
ARG foo=val1
ARG bar=val2
COPY foo.sh /foo.sh
RUN /foo.sh
```

And foo.sh:

```
echo ============
echo hello, world
echo $foo
echo $bar
echo ============
```

This prints:

```
 ---> Running in c6c8d99ba28b
============
hello, world
val1
val2
============
Removing intermediate container c6c8d99ba28b
```